# How to save debug info into particular file in qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm wondering how can I save a debug info into file named "LogFile-YYYYMMDDHHMMSS". I'm using such formula:

```
QString dt = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
QString txt = QString("[%1] ").arg(dt);

switch (type)
{
  case QtDebugMsg:
     txt += QString("{Debug} \t\t %1").arg(msg);
     break;
  case QtWarningMsg:
     txt += QString("{Warning} \t %1").arg(msg);
     break;
  case QtCriticalMsg:
     txt += QString("{Critical} \t %1").arg(msg);
     break;
  case QtFatalMsg:
     txt += QString("{Fatal} \t\t %1").arg(msg);
     abort();
     break;
}

QFile outFile( QString("LogFile.log");
outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append);

QTextStream textStream(&outFile);
textStream << txt << endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
QString dt = "LogFile";
dt += QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
dt.remove("/");
dt.remove(":");
dt += ".log";
QFile outFile( dt );
utFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append);

QTextStream textStream(&outFile);
textStream <<"test";
outFile.close();
```

You should remove this symbols because OS forbids using of this symbols in file path and your file will not be saved.

Or use easier way:

```
QString dt = "LogFile";
dt += QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("ddMMyyyy hhmmss");
dt += ".log";
```

Comment: @hyde I thought it is important for OP, but now I understood all and updated answer with easier way. Thank you for hint.

Comment: great thans, that i was looking for!

Comment: Actually, as the question is writting, this would need two different `toString` calls, because order of date components is different.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better answer uses a single datetime object (`curdt` in my example) and then produce two types of strings out of the one object. One for log information *inside* the log, and the log file name itself. We want to use a single copy of the current date/time so that what we write in the log file is the same date/time (in a different format) that appears in the log file name. If you called `QDateTime::currentDateTime()` twice it is possible to get two slightly different times.

```
/* Store a copy of the current date and time */
QDateTime curdt = QDateTime::currentDateTime();

/* Convert it to a string for logging */
QString dtstr = curdt.toString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
QString txt = QString("[%1] ").arg(dtstr);

/* Create a filename for the log */
QString logfilename = "LogFile-" + curdt.toString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + ".log";

[snip]

QFile outFile(logfilename);
```

Comment: I needed some time to rewrite my answer with this format, but you already done this, so I will not rewrite it (I upvoted your answer).

Comment: Not a problem. And thanks. This one at least deals with two formats of date/time and uses one copy of the current date&time to do it.